# C# class += operator overload

Tags: c#, oop, operator-overloading

I have a C# script that requires an item to be added or removed from a list. I thought it would be nicer to use += and -= operators.

In C# an operator is done by:

```
public Foo operator +(Foo A, Foo B){
    //Some adding code;
    return C;
}
```

however I only get a syntax error when I attempt:

```
public SpriteValues operator +=(SpriteValues A){
    //Add A to this
    return this;
}
```

I know in python it would be done using:

```
def __iadd__(self, A):
    #Add A to this
    return self
```

So how do I do this in C#?

Comment: As an aside, using operators this way is discouraged in C#. I think you will find that using +/- to represent list add/remove will become awkward or have unexpected side effects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx) you can't overload += directly but note the comment:

```
Assignment operators cannot be overloaded, but +=, for example, is evaluated using +, which can be overloaded
```

So if you only overload the `+` operator that should be fine

Answer (score 2):

You can't overload the `+=` operator as `a += b` it is just shorthand for `a = a + b`.

Overloading the `+` operator will allow you to use `+=` on your object.

Answer (score 1):

You can't overload `+=`, but it utilizes the `+` operator with the assignment, so as long as you override `+` it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I'd advocate not implementing +/- for these operations. In many cases it will result in confusing usage. Assuming your list is mutable (that's why you want add and remove operations), defining +/- becomes tricky. There are several issues to think about.

One requirement is that `+` should not cause side effects. It would be very weird if `var z = x + y` mutated `x` or `y`. Therefore, you must create new list inside +/-. Most developers would not expect this to happen and it is going to be very expensive to copy the items every time one is added.

Let's say you can live with copying on every add/remove. What would you expect the state of the program to be after executing this fragment:

```
var list1 = new MyList();
var list2 = list1;
list2 += item;
```

Most would expect that `list1` and `list2` to refer to the same list object that now has `item` in it. However, since `+` creates a new list, that is not what happens. `list1` is empty and `list2` is a different list that contains `item`. This is very weird.

You either have to drop the requirement that the list is mutable, +/- won't cause side effects, or the expectation that += won't create a new list. Of course, in the framework delegates have these operators and they are immutable. The behavior of +/- for delegates is one of the more confusing parts of the language so I would not advocate that you emulate it.

I would go the normal route of implementing Add/Remove methods who semantics are well-known and can be easily predicted.

Answer (score -2):

Lists are very common, generic classes, and as such have well-known methods by which things can be added to or removed from them (namely Add and Remove).

If you go overloading operators instead you'll just confuse the heck out of the poor guy that will come along and have to maintain your code once you're gone.